# Isomorphism between $E$ and $Lin(E)$ : infinite dimensional case.

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems, vector-space-isomorphism, exceptional-isomorphisms

> Does $E$ and $Lin(E)$ where $Lin(E)=\{A : E \rightarrow E ∣ A \quad\text{is linear}\}$ are isomorph if $E$ infinite dimensional case ?

I know that if $E$ is finite dimension the result is true if and only if the dimension is $0$ or $1$ . I am tempted to say the result is false because they are not equipotent by [Kaplansky theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplansky_density_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

**No**. Let $B$ be a Hamel basis of $E$. Each function $f\colon B\to E$ extends uniquely to a linear map. By Cantor's theorem $|E|^{|B|}>|B|=\dim E$.

Comment: Don't you mean $|B|=\dim E$?

Comment: Sure, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Now it is possible that $\dim E < |E|$, so this inequality does not really help to answer.

Comment: @TomekKania Have you seen Siméon's commment ?